# Extracting the shadows layer of an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image of a pillow, I need to create another png image which is only the shadows of this image, so for :

[image]

I need to get a png with the **shadows and wrinkles** on the edges, so that if I put it on another **flat pillow mask** (just a flat shape), it will look real.

What are the steps to do that (not a pro user)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open the Channels panel. CTRL+click on the red channel to make a
  selection from the channel
- Return to the layers panel, and click *Select >  Inverse*
- Click the New Layer mask icon in the Layers panel
- Click the coloured layer thumbnail to select it
- Click *Image > Adjustments > Desaturate*

[image]

Comment: Also, why you choose the Red channel ? if the pillow was White, what would you choose ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also, why am i not able to do the same on a transparent pillow? I get the same effect but when trying to save as a png, it saved the original photo

Comment: @Curnelious I chose red because it is the lightest channel, you could use any channel you want.  I don't know what you mean by "a transparent pillow".  If you mean the background is already transparent, it should make no difference.  If you have a background layer, make sure it is hidden or deleted before you export as png.